# Zevenet Load Balancer - SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, private-key, public-key, pem, csr

I am wondering if anyone has any experience with Zevenet Load Balancers.

I have setup the community version (V4). I have 2 web servers with replicated content, I have a virtual IP setup in the system which points to the 2 IP addresses of the web servers. The load balancer works for HTTP and HTTPS traffic correctly but shows an cert error when trying to get to the servers via HTTPS.

I want to combat this by adding a certificate to the load balancer. To do this I have followed the these steps:

https://www.zevenet.com/knowledge-base/howtos/manage-certificates-with-zen-load-balancer/ (ignoring the bit about purchasing a cert from SofIntel as we use JISC for our Certs)

Basically I created a certificate in the load balancer, generated the CSR, purchased a certificate from JISC by uploading the CSR generated from the load balancer.

I then downloaded the ZIP file from JISC which contains the crt for the domain, as well as the root certificates required also in the ZIP.

I tried uploading the ZIP to the load balancer and it pops up an error showing that the certificate needs to be created in a PEM format.

I then found this here:

https://www.zevenet.com/knowledge-base/howtos/create-certificates-pem-format/

I am not really sure what this is asking me to do....does this mean the original CSR that I generated is irrelevant now? The instructions on the above link say that the PEM file needs to be the following:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- Private Key (without passphrase) -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- Certificate (CN=www.mydomain.com) -----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- Intermediate (Intermediate CA, if exists) -----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- Root (ROOT CA, who signs the Certificate) -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Essentially I already have the domain certificate, the intermediate and the root all from JISC now. But is there any way  can go about getting the Private key from the load balancer so that I can just create the PEM file manually.

I am pretty new to cert stuff, not sure why it wont just let me upload the zip file.

Comment: Really more of a question for [sf] than a programming question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will go over there, still very new to this site, not used it much, thanks for the comment :)

Comment: You can flag this post for moderator attention and ask to have it migrated over to [sf] so you don't have to re-post.

Comment: @Filburt thanks for that, i have just reposted it now, i will remember that for next time. Thanks very much :)